# How does this PostgreSQL query slow down when the number of rows increases?

Tags: postgresql, optimization

I have a table briefly structured like this:

```
tn( id integer NOT NULL primary key DEFAULT nextval('tn_sequence'),
                 create_dt TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
                             ...............
                 deleted boolean );
```

`create_dt` is the timestamp when the row is inserted into the database.

`deleted` indicates that the row is or no longer useful.

And I have the following queries:

```
select * from tn where create_dt > ( NOW() - interval '150 seconds ) and deleted = FALSE;
select * from tn where create_dt < ( NOW() - interval '150 seconds ) and deleted = FALSE;
```

My question is how these query will slow down when the number of rows increase? For instance, when the number of rows exceeds 10K, 20K, or 100K, will it make a big impact on the speed? Is there any way I can optimize these queries? Note that every 5 seconds I will turn the column 'deleted' of rows which are older than 150 seconds into 'TRUE'.

Comment: `primary key` implies `not null` so the later is not necessary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The effect of table growth on performance will depend on the query plan chosen, available indexes, the selectivity of the query, and lots of other factors. `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` on the query might help. In short, if your query only selects a few rows and can use a simple b-tree index then it won't usually slow down tons, only a little as the index grows. On the other hand queries using complex non-indexed conditions or returning lots of rows could perform very badly indeed.

Your issue appears to mirror that in the question [How should we handle rows which won't be queried once they are old in PostgreSQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25129/how-should-we-handle-rows-which-wont-be-queried-once-they-are-old-in-postgresql)

The advice given there should apply:

- Use a [partial index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-partial.html) with the condition `WHERE (not deleted)`; or
- [partition](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-partitioning.html) on 'deleted' with [constraint exclusion](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-query.html#GUC-CONSTRAINT-EXCLUSION) enabled.

For example, you might:

```
CREATE INDEX create_dt_when_not_deleted_idx 
ON tn (create_dt)
WHERE (NOT deleted);
```

This includes only rows where `deleted = 'f'` (assuming `deleted` is `not null) in the index. This isn't the same as having them gone from the table completely.

- Nothing changes with full table sequential scans, the `deleted='t'` rows must still be scanned; and
- There's more I/O than if the `deleted = 't'` rows weren't there because any given heap page is likely to contain a mix of `deleted = 't'` and `deleted = 'f'` rows.

You can reduce the impact of the latter by `CLUSTER`ing on an index that includes `deleted`. Again, this will have no effect on sequential scans. To help with sequential scans you would have to partition the table on `deleted`.

Pg 9.2's index only scans should (I think, haven't tested) use the partial index. When an index only scan is possible the partial index should be as fast as an index on a table containing only the `deleted = 'f'` rows.

Note that you'll need to keep table and index bloat under control. Ensure autovaccum runs very frequently and use a current version of PostgreSQL that doesn't need things like manually-managed free space map and has the latest, best-behaved autovacuum. I'd recommend 9.0 or above, preferably 9.1 or 9.2. Tune autovacuum to run aggressively.

When tuning and testing performance - test your queries with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`, don't just guess.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker Um, whoops. Fixed.

Comment: Sorry for keeping picking on you, but in the example you say `when`, not `where` ;-)

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker No, thankyou. Clearly too tired to be writing answers. Fixed.

Comment: @ Craig Ringer: thanks heaps Craig. So by adding this to the sql script.
CREATE INDEX create_dt_when_not_deleted_idx 
ON tn (create_dt)
WHERE (NOT deleted);
then the create_dt will be partial indexed, and the row with 'deleted' = true wont be indexed, as a result wont be cared in the query?

Comment: @user1726452 That's a bit simplistic but mostly right. It means the rows with `deleted = false` won't affect the *index*. They're still there in the table, so they'll affect full table sequential scans and will increase I/O because any given heap page is likely to contain a mix of `deleted = true` and `deleted = false` rows. You can improve the latter problem by `CLUSTER`ing the table on `deleted` or solve both by partitioning by `deleted`. In practice it might not matter - *test your queries* with `explain analyze`, don't just guess.